# ModelViewset in django

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm newbie of Django Rest-framework. I use Modelviewset to create API for project. I want to get list of thing not by id and i use lookup_field to do that. But it is only return 1 object. How can i custom it to return multible object?

this is my model

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    dayandtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ratingpoint = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    ratingcomment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='static',default=None)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my views

```
class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rating.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer
    lookup_field = "product"
```

This is my Serializer

```
class RatingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Rating
        fields=["id","dayandtime","ratingpoint", "ratingcomment","img","product","user"]
        lookup_field = "product"
```

Please help me to sovle this problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You want to use filter on the api and return multiple objects. But `lookup_field` is *used to for performing object lookup of individual model instances*.
There are many way to achieve your goal, but i'll show you [filter by query parameters](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters).

You can override `get_queryset()` to deal with URLs such as `http://yourdoamin.com/api/ratings?product=1` ( here we assume that you want to filter by product id ).

```
class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Rating.objects.all()
        product= self.request.query_params.get('product')
        if product not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(product_id=product)
        return queryset
```

Of course, you can add many `if/elif/else` block to handle many query parameters.

You can also use a similar method : [The SearchFilter class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) to achieve the same goal.

More info on the [DRF filtering documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)